# how to modify Drawer opening methods on android application?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gesture, navigation-drawer

I'm using Navigation Drawer to navigate between Fragments, right now the drawer can be opened with two ways:

1. by click on item in my action bar , this is easy to modify List item
2. by swipe gesture from left to right

**My problem is that the swipe area is to narrow**,  only if you swipe from the very start of the left side the drawer will open.

I want to extend this area, so the "swipe area" can begin on wider area. So if you begin your left to right gesture it will open the drawer ever if you begin the gesture a bit far from the left side.

Comment: As per my understanding, navigation drawer swipe area restricted to very start of left side because it will make issue if the content fragment contains a sliding component like view pager.

Comment: i"m sure you are right , and if i had view pager i wouldn't want that but maybe that can be modify'd or maybe not i don't know . if someone will know is one of the stackoverflow members

Comment: you could maybe do a hack and add another gesture detector over the fragments, and if one is swiped then open the drawer.  Not elegant, but should get the job done.

Comment: Today I noticed, latest YouTube have this feature !!!! I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: it guess it can be achived by simple gesture listener , but i dont want to use this solution .

Comment: hi. try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988597/set-drag-margin-for-android-navigation-drawer/17802569#17802569