# How to set closing animation duration for navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using android navigation drawer. I want to override default closing animation delay for navigation drawer. And also how can specify swiping edge length for drawer?

Answer (score 0):

For you first question - take a look at this: [Speed up 'Navigation Drawer' animation speed on closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460683/speed-up-navigation-drawer-animation-speed-on-closing)

It seems like you'd be able to alter the animation but it requires some digging into the classes (not recommended). As of right now there is no public method you can call to alter the default animation time.

For your second question - take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802569/2596906
It shows how to increase the margin of touch for your swipe gesture.