# How to increase the width of pulling the Navigation Drawer from the side

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

Is there an API to increase the width/sensitivity of pulling the Navigation Drawer from the left side of the screen? For ex: as of now, I need to press my finger closely to the left of the screen to pull the drawer out. I would like to increase this sensitivity.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot increase the pull area of the `NavigationDrawer`. Google didn't choose the current value lightly. It should be a pretty good compromise between ease of use and the chance to unintentionally open the drawer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution. You can Set drag margin for your Navigation Drawer

Check this link
[Set drag margin for Android Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988597/set-drag-margin-for-android-navigation-drawer/17802569#17802569)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do that since the users could easily pop open the Navigation Drawer by pressing the title area iff you implement the `DrawerListener`interface or the more convinient `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class to provide the 3 horizontal line icon indicating there is Navigation Drawer being present. Then you just override the `onPostCreate()` method in your Activity and call `ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()` method to allow users to open the drawer by pressing about the title area. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for more info on how to achieve that. Hope this helps