# eclipse- Open Navigation Drawer WIth Swiping

Tags: android, eclipse

I've made a material navigation drawer and it works great and i can open it when I swipe from the left edge of the screen to right but i want to swipe anywhere of the screen to  open it so i added swipe gestures.
I could make toast with that but java files where so messy and complicated so i can't add the thing i want.
can somebody help me? 
the app i saw this thing for the first time is Telegram messaging app.
you can swipe the middle of the screen to right to open navigation drawer
and besides i want to keep the effect

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645537/how-to-detect-the-swipe-left-or-right-in-android to detect the swipe ... and then in onswipe detect open your navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

Here is 1 solution to your problem.
Using reflection code you can change left drawer margin
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802569/4498813