# How to open drawerlayout by sliding from anywhere?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio, drawerlayout

I want to know how to open drawerlayout from left by sliding anywhere in view of the layout.

I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71389377/21290837, but it didn't let me to initialize my drawerlayout in the end.

EDIT

XML:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </include>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

...

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.fish ->
                adapter?.updateAdapter(fillArrays(resources.getStringArray(R.array.fish_name),
                    (resources.getStringArray(R.array.content)),
                    getImageId(R.array.fish_image_array)))
            R.id.location ->
                adapter?.updateAdapter(fillArrays(resources.getStringArray(R.array.location_name),
                    (resources.getStringArray(R.array.location_content)),
                    getImageId(R.array.location_image_array)))
        }

        binding.dLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

        return true
    }

...

}
```