# Closing navigation drawer smoothly

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have implemented navigation drawer in a slightly different way in my app. But the drawer doesn't open or close smoothly. It lags in between. In Google apps, the navigation drawer is so smooth. How do I achieve it? This question is already asked here but it didn't meet my needs. Please help!

**XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Swipe from the left to open the drawer"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-65dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#bfc2d1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Search" >
    </EditText>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-65dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_text"
        android:text="@string/notfound"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffababab"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
final String[] data ={"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Flourine","Noen","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium",
        "Iodine","Xenon","Caesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","gadoliium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einstenium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium",
        "Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Ununtrium","Ununquadium","Ununpentium","Ununhexium","Ununseptium","Ununoctium"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    final EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);


    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            drawer.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    });

    //filter list view after search instantly
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            String searchedquery = cs.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(searchedquery);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    //hide the keyboard after search on touch list view
    navList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(navList.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });

    navList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

 }

}
```

Comment: If it hickups, it's most likely because you're doing some heavy calculations on the UI thread, therefore blocking the view drawing. Check your logcat for hints of "dropped XXX frames".

Comment: @Neik It shows nothing about droped frames.

Comment: Where is your navigationdrawer fragment?

Comment: Late is better than never, for those who want a good applicable solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18872933/1663135

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to make the sliding smooth

1. Create the layout of the navigation Drawer separately
2. Call the Drawer from the fragment

Here is the code for better understanding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/custom_drawer_layout">

    <fragment 
//this contains the layout of your fragment
        android:id="@+id/drawer_fragement"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:name="adress to navigationdrawer class"
        tools:layout="@layout/drawer_frag
//this line tells which layout to inflate ontop of the fragment
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now Create a loyout with name as drawer_frag which contains all your code that you want to display in you drawer

Hope it helps

Comment: post your answer there